# mongoose sorting by ascending order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

```js
const followingUsers = await User.find({ _id: { $in: foundUser.followings } })
const getFeedData = async() => {
    let data = []
    for (let user of followingUsers) {
        const userPosts = user.posts
        for (let post of userPosts) {
            const posts = await Post.find({ _id: post })
            for (let post of posts) {
                const foundPost = await Post.findById(post._id).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
                data.push(foundPost)
            }
        }
    }
    return data
}
const posts = await getFeedData()
```

Here is some sample data, imagine there are identical two users
and I want to get their posts and sort them by ascending order, those
two users are the users I follow and I need to get all their posts
and show them on the news feed

```json
   "user": [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("625c053cfdd023e3713b297f"),
      email: "user1@yahoo.com",
      isAdmin: false,
      chats: [],
      blockedChats: [],
      feedback: [],
      plans: [],
      posts: [
        ObjectId("625c0577fdd023e3713b29c7"),
        ObjectId("625c0582fdd023e3713b29f5"),
        ObjectId("625c075f8f794ea1fcf6c6af"),
        ObjectId("625c4a742db74795a43d5243")
      ],
      opportunities: [],
      username: "sam",
      createdAt: ISODate("2022-04-17T12:17:01.095Z"),
      updatedAt: ISODate("2022-04-17T17:12:20.341Z"),
      __v: 4
    }
  ],
  "post": [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("625c0577fdd023e3713b29c7"),
      postText: "hi this is sam\r\n",
      likes: [],
      likesCount: [],
      timePosted: ISODate("2022-04-17T12:09:05.535Z"),
      postImage: [],
      user: ObjectId("625c053cfdd023e3713b297f"),
      createdAt: ISODate("2022-04-01T00:00:00.00Z")
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId("625c075f8f794ea1fcf6c6af"),
      postText: "it works !!!",
      likes: [],
      likesCount: [],
      timePosted: ISODate("2022-04-17T12:20:08.794Z"),
      postImage: [],
      user: ObjectId("625c053cfdd023e3713b297f"),
      createdAt: ISODate("2022-04-17T12:26:07.075Z"),
      updatedAt: ISODate("2022-04-17T12:26:07.075Z")
    }
  ]
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gXecTgdWDQN)

everything is working okay, except the documents that I'm retrieving back are not in ascending order, it may also be due to the loops, or maybe to perform as less as possible queries to the database, what's the problem here can anyone help?

Comment: Your logic seems weird and imperformant in the way that you are iterating the post ids and perform multiple queries to the database. It is suggested to perform as less as possible queries to database. We can see what we can help if you can provide sample dataset in json documents and the expected output.

Comment: @ray I posted below some sample data, imagine there are identical two users and I want to get their posts and sort them by ascending order, those two users are the users I follow and I need to get all their posts and show them on the feed

Comment: I presume you have 2 collections: `user` and `post`, and the structure is somewhat similar to [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RPy9qX35zr7)? Can you help to fill in your `post` collection with some of your current documents?

Comment: yes [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NwC92_YEKBD) is some data for the post model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably achieving the same logic through `$lookup`.

```js
const getFeedData = async() => {
    const foundPost = await User.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            _id: {
              $in: foundUser.followings
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "post",
            "let": {
              posts: "$posts"
            },
            "pipeline": [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    "$in": [
                      "$_id",
                      "$$posts"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "$sort": {
                  createdAt: -1
                }
              }
            ],
            "as": "postLookup"
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": "$postLookup"
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$postLookup"
          }
        }
      ])
    return foundPost
}
const posts = await getFeedData()
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KUxyLMNmVZL) for your reference.

Comment: by using this query, I get the user with an additional section of postLookup is there a chance to get only the posts in ascending order?

Comment: @MarkoS sorry my bad. I have added 2 more stages of `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot` to wrangle the result to contain post only. Also updated the javascript part.

Comment: okay thank you very much I appreciate the effort 